# hard delete events on kafka-connect to sync databases doesn't work or gives a error

Tags: mysql, postgresql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

i had connect my postgres data base to sync on MySql database.

The create and update events work's fine on sink, but when i delete a row on source (no just a data from  column) it's gives a error.

I've tried somethings but without lucky.

1 -  When i don't put "createKey" and "extractInt" in "transform" on my MySql Sink, i receive a error and the column don't create with bigserial.

**"BLOB/TEXT column 'id_consultor' used in key specification without a key length".**

2 - But if i put in my configurations to "createKey" and  "extractInt" work's fine on create and delete, but gives this error on delete events:

**"Only Map objects supported in absence of schema for [copying fields from value to key], found: null".**

```
"transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
"transforms.createKey.fields":"id_consultor",   
"transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
"transforms.extractInt.field": "id_consultor"
```

3 - If i put on my source (Postgres)

```
**"transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite"**
```

The delete works partially executing a "soft delete" don't  erase the row, just erase all data and preserve not null fields filling with 0.

Somebody could help me? Thanks!

Postgres Connector:

```
  "name": "postgres-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.hostname": "**",
    "database.port": "5432",
    "database.user": "**",
    "database.password": "**",
    "database.dbname" : "**",
    "database.server.name": "kafkaPostgres",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "history",
    "schema.include.list": "public",
    "table.include.list": "public.consultor",
    "time.precision.mode": "connect",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "true",
    "plugin.name": "pgoutput",
    "transforms": "unwrap, dropPrefix",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.fields": "table,lsn",
    "transforms.unwrap.add.headers": "db",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"kafkaPostgres.public.(.*)",
    "transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"$1"
```

MySql Sink:

```
"name": "mysql-sink",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "consultor",
    "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "connection.url": "**,
    "connection.user":"**",
    "connection.password":"**",
    "auto.create": "true",
    "auto.evolve": "true",
    "insert.mode": "upsert",
    "dialect.name": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
    "Database Dialect": "MySqlDatabaseDialect",
    "table.name.format": "consultor",
    "pk.mode": "record_key",
    "pk.fields": "id_consultor",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "drop.invalid.message": "true",
    "delete.retention.ms": 1,
    "fields.whitelist": "id_consultor, idempresaorganizacional, cd_consultor_cpf, dt_consultor_nascimento , ds_justificativa, nn_consultor , cd_consultor_rg, id_motivo, id_situacao , id_sub_motivo",
    "transforms": "unwrap, flatten, route, createKey, extractInt ",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode":"rewrite",
    "transforms.flatten.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
    "transforms.flatten.delimiter": ".",
    "transforms.route.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter",
    "transforms.route.regex": "(?:[^.]+)\\.(?:[^.]+)\\.([^.]+)",
    "transforms.route.replacement": "$1",
    "transforms.createKey.type":"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
    "transforms.createKey.fields":"id_consultor",   
    "transforms.extractInt.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.extractInt.field": "id_consultor"
```

Answer (score 0):

i've added this properties on connector:

```
"key.converter": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.url" :"http://apicurio:8080/api",
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.global-id": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.GetOrCreateIdStrategy",
"value.converter": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.apicurio.registry.url":"http://apicurio:8080/api",
"value.converter.apicurio.registry.global-id": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.GetOrCreateIdStrategy",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
```

and replaces this on sink:

```
 "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
```

to:

```
"key.converter": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.AvroConverter",
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.url" :"http://apicurio:8080/api",
"key.converter.apicurio.registry.global-id": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.GetOrCreateIdStrategy",
"value.converter": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.converter.AvroConverter",
"value.converter.apicurio.registry.url":"http://apicurio:8080/api",
"value.converter.apicurio.registry.global-id": "io.apicurio.registry.utils.serde.strategy.GetOrCreateIdStrategy",
"key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
"value.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
```

and everything worked well, but i can't read the mensages in topic because i'm using the debezium kafka version and there hasn't a avro console reader.

Now i'm try to some plugin for this version to able read avro files.

I hope  help's somebody.